# AWS Elastic BeanStalk Security Group

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to create Worker Environmenton EBS with Sample Application of Node js which should use existing Security group on VPC.

I create this environment inside VPC (Virtual Private Cloud).

When I create this environment, I keep following configuration for VPC. 
Security Group which is selected here is already exist.

[image: VPS Configuration]

In the next screen, I also select instance profile and service role which also exist.

[image: VPC Configuration and permission]

While I create Environment with this setting, It does create Environment fine but it always create new Security group instead of using existing security group.

[image: New Security Group created]

Why it always create new Security group and not use existing one ? 
I want to reuse Security group and not create separate for each worker environment.

Appreciate if someone can guide me in right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beanstalk uses the security group you asked for, but on creation it also creates a unique one for that configuration. If you launch your instance it will be in the security group as expected.

Comment: Thanks Marc for response. Once  instance is created, when I check in configuration, It shows 2 security group. One which i have selected and one which is created during this instance creation.

Comment: @Marc, I create similar config using eb extensions. I don't know though, why it creates an extra security group and I just hope it won't interfere with my chosen one (OR relation?). Can you paste link to some explanation or elaborate? Thanks

Comment: Beanstalk is driven by cloudformation, and there's likely a connection that requires it for things to talk to each other outside of your dependencies. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.ec2.html . Quote: "Elastic Beanstalk creates a default security group for you. You can view the security group name in the EC2 security group box."

Answer (score 1):

Instead of stopping it from being created, was able to modify its rules such that I changed to just allow port 22 access only from my private security group.

```
Namespace: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration
OptionName: SSHSourceRestriction
Value: tcp, 22, 22, my-private-security-group
```

Visit : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html#SSHSourceRestriction